# Why does NOEXEC not prevent the specified program from running?

Tags: sudo

I have tried the NOEXEC in my CentOS6.4 I have edited my `/etc/sudo.conf` file as below :

```
Path noexec /usr/libexec/sudo_noexec.so
```

and `/etc/sudoers`:

```
ssh ALL=(root) ALL,NOEXEC:/usr/bin/passwd
```

I am sure that the lib for noexec exists in the right path, but as the user ssh still can change password. The NOEXEC did not make any effect, can anyone give some suggestions on it?

Answer (score 6):

The `NOEXEC` tag doesn't prevent programs from getting executed. It prevents listed programs from executing any other programs. From [man sudoers](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.7.10/sudoers.man.html):

> ```
> aaron  shanty = NOEXEC: /usr/bin/more, /usr/bin/vi
> ```
>
> This allows user aaron to run /usr/bin/more and /usr/bin/vi with noexec enabled.
>   This will prevent those two commands from executing other commands (such as a shell).
>   If you are unsure whether or not your system is capable of supporting noexec you can
>   always just try it out and check whether shell escapes work when noexec is enabled.

If you want to prevent users from executing a specific command have a look at `!`, e.g:

```
ssh ALL=(root) ALL, !/usr/bin/passwd
```

Please note that this line does not help much as it would be possible to create a copy of `/usr/bin/passwd` under a different name, copy one onto the host and set the appropriate permissions etc.

Comment: wow,get it.So it prevent the shell escape such as less ,more ?Nice of you,thank you